# How can we encourage people to ask more questions?

Tags: discusión, preguntas, actividad-reciente

I was just looking through recent questions on the site, and realized that in the past seven days, 27 out of the 33 questions asked were created by myself and just two other users. I realize we're still fairly early in the beta, but I think it would be great if we could get more people asking questions. Even bad questions (that get closed) would at least help define the site and help with SEO. Any suggestions?

Maybe as other sites have done we could pick weekly topics (the subjunctive mood, pronouns, medical vocabulary, whatever) and challenge users to think of questions to ask in those areas?

Comment: Yes I agree with you, the thing is that it is almost Christmas and everyone is in holidays. I am not being very active lately either, just enough to moderate actually. Nonetheless, in the general sense I think we should indeed encourage more questions from others myself included. That is a very good suggestion!! How did the other sites implement it? I'll try consulting with the community and get back to you. :)

Comment: True, I'm still at work so I didn't think of that :) There's some info on what the other sites did in a [recent blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/12/own-your-community-2/).

Comment: Over on Philosophy, they [have a topics challenge](http://meta.philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/291/its-descartes-week) for question-asking that rotates each week. It's totally adaptable to the Spanish site, imho!

Comment: I really like your idea and I also appreciate your effort asking interesting questions. Let's implement your proposal.

Answer (score 4):

I think we should hold off on the topic challenges until we have enough traffic (especially on meta) for people to notice and respond.

For those of us that are around in the meantime, I'd encourage others to do what I've been doing: In your day-to-day life, think about phrases or concepts in Spanish to describe what's around you. If any good questions come to mind (even if you already know the answer), post them! More questions means more search engine traffic which means better progress towards the site leaving beta one day. There are literally millions of questions about Spanish Language & Usage that could be asked, we just need people to start asking them!