# This is translation-golf! The translation with the least number of characters wins!

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, promoción-de-la-comunidad, juegos

In [a recent question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/20209/12637) in Spanish Language, and based on the [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) stack, I came up with the idea of creating a game-like type of questions in which the goal is to translate a text from another language into Spanish, using the least possible number of characters while respecting the original meaning of the sentence.

It is usually said that a translation from English to Spanish makes the translated text about <strike>1,1</strike> 1,2 times larger than the original one. Maybe we will be able to prove it wrong! :)

If you think this could be a nice idea to make the site a bit more alive, help us [defining the rules](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2592/12637) of the game in the community wiki answer below!

Let's make a [translation-golf](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation-golf) tag and let the game begin!

Comment: This is simply brilliant. I don't know if the 1:1 criteria is the best choice, but it is definitely an easy one and it is going to make the contest proposals clear and fun.

Comment: In fact [they say](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/3022/37429) _Spanish, Portuguese and French (I guess we can just settle on Romance) texts are longer than their English counterparts by about 1/5 to 1/4_.

Comment: This is weird. Note that with 4100 questions, this beta is in the stage of inactivity that would/should change by time passing, and the idea is bold, but might end up hurting the site more than helping it. (More activity, but for what cost?)

Comment: Related: https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/153/2591 (similar intent)

Comment: I think while the length brevity is an interesting one, we could also alternate with word count golfing.  That would employ a different strategy (no, no, I swear my tendency for proclisis isn't part of this request) and probably encourage a different set of vocabulary to emerge.

Comment: @guifa if we do that, everyone will end up writing proclitics and the results will be more similar to German than to Spanish. :-D But we may leave that to the asker's choice.

Comment: @M.A.R. this is indeed a good point that I appreciate you bring to our attention. We have been in Beta for over 5 years now and our numbers are a bit flat, probably due to lack of people. This idea may help in various ways: get more people notice the site, accustom users to answering (our answer ratio is quite low) and, of course, dig more into the Spanish subtleties. A limit on these kind of questions seems to be necessary (once per week or so?) so we are sure the focus does remain where it should be. Let's see how it works for few weeks and then analyze the impact with proper data.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo Actually, I was thinking more of showing off Spanish's rich number of prefixes and suffixes and some of the more interesting (but specific) words like "procrastinar", "vislumbrar", "yuxtaponer", "embadunar", etc, that would serve to expand the vocabulary of newer speakers (doing it by letter count has a different purpose: showing off the flexibility of the shorter words)

Comment: [They talk about this](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/q/675/10449) in [french.se]!

Comment: @M.A.R. - I don't understand.  Could you expand on your concern, that the game could hurt the site?  How?  I'm not disagreeing, I want to understand.

Comment: @guifa - "proclitic" is new to me.  I looked up a definition but I'm still not with you.  Could you show a couple of examples of what your game would look like and explain the proclitic thing in that context?

Comment: @aparente001 [Sites risk becoming a doughnut when you bring in fun questions that see a lot of views and activity.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57383/give-each-site-a-parallel-site-for-polling-recommendations-and-subjective-ish-s) It seems that these questions attract a lot of views at first, but people tend to just read them than contribute anything to them, so the site ends up with a big hole in the middle.

Comment: @M.A.R. - Thanks for explaining.  I think I understand.  Whenever there's a question on Academia SE about revealing clothing or sexual ethics on campus, whoosh, the hordes descend. (So far that has not happened with our translation golf game.)

Comment: I tried to add two tags, translation and translation-golf, but it didn't work.

Comment: @walen good one. No one dared to write a number in that recent game indeed. I supposed we all respected the original text: as it was written with letters in the original, we all wrote letters in the translation. I don't think we should write rules for every particular case, so we are just using fair play. In case of doubt the OP decides.

Answer (score 7):

## English

### Translation-golf rules

> **Important notice:** There can be only one active edition of a [translation-golf](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation-golf) game at any given time. The winner of the current game will have the right to ask the next question within the next 48 hours after his/her proclamation. After that, if no new game exists, any person can ask the next question. Also, all questions and answers participating in the game are expected to be converted to *community wiki* in order not to gain reputation from a game.

**Rule 0**. In case of doubt while applying the following rules, **the asking user, or Original Poster (OP), will always have the last word** deciding if an answer is acceptable or who the winner is (for instance, when a translation is shorter than other, but the OP thinks it does not respect the original sense).

Rules:

1. **The translation must be accurate and respect the original sentence.** This can be sometimes a debatable subject, so questions participating in this tag must contain easily-translatable sentences: not very long and easy to understand. The final purpose must be the learning of constructions and words in Spanish apart from what we use in everyday sentences.
2. Translations may come from any language. If the original language is not English, it could be nice to have an English translation, or an explanation of what the original sentence means.
3. **The OP always needs to propose a first attempt of translation to Spanish**, in order to follow the rules governing every question in the stack. This is **just to show that you do not need a translation, and that you are just golfing**. The initial translation can be a long one on purpose to give others the chance of playing the game, and can be hidden using the [spoiler markdown](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/editing-help#spoilers) in order not to bias the answers.
4. **The translation with the least number of characters wins**, and must be marked as the accepted answer by the OP **after a week**, which will be the standard duration of a game.
5. The spaces and punctuation marks do not count as characters. Only letters (including letters with diacritics) and numbers count, so *"Hola, ¿qué tal?"* and *"Tal que hola"* have the same count.
6. **Words used for translations must appear in the *[Diccionario de la Lengua Española](http://www.rae.es/)* or in the *[Diccionario de Americanismos](http://www.asale.org/)*.** In case the translation needs an invented word or neologism, it will be explained etymologically.
7. If the proposed translation uses very uncommon or regional words or expressions, the participant must link to their respective entries in any of the valid dictionaries.
8. **No abbreviations are allowed.** You cannot write *"Sr."* if you need to write *"señor"*. Note that you can use shortened versions of words if they appear in the dictionary: *[seño](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Xc805A7)* is valid instead of *señorita* when referring to female teachers; *[profe](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UHpdmf1)* is valid for *profesor*.
9. If a foreign word does not specify gender, any gender can be used for the translation: so *teacher* could be translated both as *profesor* or *profesora* (the male option wins) or both as *seño* or *profe* (the female option wins).
10. **Answers must be consistent in the sense of not mixing words from different regions.** Answers must then use standard Spanish or a specified regional variant. If you use a specific word from Argentina you cannot use another one from Colombia. Thus we may find what Spanish variant uses the least characters.
11. Questions can ask for the answer to be in a given Spanish variant using the established regional tags.
12. **Participants are free to edit and enhance their answers** as much as they want during the game. The OP can keep an eye on such changes and warn the authors about any broken rules before the game ends; however, **Rule 0** still applies.

Every question participating in this game must follow these rules or it will be deleted. Also, the question must be tagged with the [juego](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/juego) tag to note that the question is a game, and the [translation-golf](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation-golf) tag to note the particular kind of game it is (we may come up with more games in the future).

And finally, remember that the ultimate purpose of the game is to learn something new: discover new words, find new expressions, or just practice the language, so keep a good mood and respect others. **If you do not agree with an answer, just leave a polite comment explaining your complaint** and let others decide who is right. OP will always have the last word.

---

## Español

### Reglas del Translation Golf

> **Aviso importante:** Sólo puede haber una edición activa del juego de [translation-golf](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation-golf) en un momento dado. El ganador del juego podrá plantear un nuevo juego en las siguientes 48 horas después de su proclamación, si pasado ese plazo no ha planteado ningún juego cualquier persona podrá hacer la siguiente pregunta. Se espera que todas las preguntas y respuestas que participen en el juego se conviertan en *wiki de comunidad* con el fin de no ganar reputación con el juego.

**Regla 0**. En caso de duda al aplicar las siguientes reglas, **quien propone el juego (el OP) siempre tendrá la última palabra** para decidir si una respuesta es aceptable o quién es el ganador (por ejemplo, cuando una traducción es más corta que otra, pero el OP cree que no respeta el sentido original).

Reglas:

1. **La traducción debe ser precisa y respetar el original**. Esto puede ser a veces un tema discutible, por lo que las preguntas con esta etiqueta deben contener frases fácilmente traducibles: no muy largas larga y fáciles de entender. El propósito final debe ser el aprendizaje de construcciones y palabras en español aparte de lo que solemos utilizar en frases cotidianas.
2. Las traducciones pueden provenir de cualquier idioma. Si el idioma original no es el inglés, sería bueno tener una traducción en inglés, o una explicación de lo que significa el texto original.
3. **El OP debe siempre proponer un primer intento de traducción al español** para seguir las reglas que rigen en las preguntas del sitio. **Esto es sólo para demostrar que no necesitas una traducción y que se trata de un juego**. La traducción inicial puede ser larga a propósito para dar a otros la oportunidad de jugar y se puede ocultar con la [marca de spoiler de Markdown](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/editing-help#spoilers) para no influir en las respuestas.
4. **Gana la traducción con el menor número de caracteres** y debe ser marcada como la respuesta aceptada **al cabo de una semana**, que será la duración estándar de un juego.
5. Los espacios y signos de puntuación no cuentan como caracteres. Sólo las letras (incluyendo letras con diacríticos) y los números cuentan, así que "Hola, ¿qué tal?" y "Tal que hola" tienen el mismo número de caracteres.
6. **Las palabras utilizadas para las traducciones deben aparecer en el [Diccionario de la Lengua Española](http://www.rae.es/) o en el [Diccionario de Americanismos](http://www.asale.org/).** En el caso de que la traducción necesite una palabra inventada o neologismo, se explicará etimológicamente.
7. Si la traducción propuesta es demasiado críptica (utiliza palabras o expresiones muy poco comunes o regionales), se deben enlazar los términos a sus respectivas entradas en cualquiera de los diccionarios válidos.
8. **No se permiten abreviaturas**. Si necesitas escribir "señor" no puedes escribir "Sr.". Ten en cuenta que puedes utilizar versiones abreviadas de palabras si aparecen en el diccionario: [seño](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Xc805A7) es válido en lugar de señorita cuando se refiere a las profesoras; [profe](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UHpdmf1) es válido para profesor.
9. Si una palabra extranjera no especifica género, se puede usar cualquier género para la traducción, por lo tanto *teacher* puede traducirse como profesor o profesora (la opción masculina gana) o ambos como seño o profe (la opción femenina gana).
10. **Las respuestas deben ser consistentes en el sentido de no mezclar palabras de diferentes regiones**. Las respuestas deben usar español neutro o una variante regional. Si usa una palabra específica de Argentina no puede usar otra de Colombia. Así podremos encontrar la variante española que utiliza menos caracteres.
11. Las preguntas pueden pedir que la respuesta esté en una variante española dada, usando las etiquetas regionales establecidas.
12. **Los participantes podrán editar y mejorar sus respuestas** todo lo que quieran mientras dure el juego. El OP podrá revisar estos cambios y avisar a los autores si rompen alguna regla, antes de que acabe el juego; no obstante, la **Regla 0** se aplica igual.

Cada pregunta que participe en este juego debe seguir estas reglas o se eliminará. La pregunta debe ser etiquetada con la etiqueta [juego](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/juego) para dejar claro que la pregunta es un juego y la etiqueta [traslation-golf](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/traslation-golf) para definir el tipo particular de juego que es (puede haber otros juegos en el futuro).

Y por último, recuerda que el propósito último del juego es aprender algo nuevo: descubre nuevas palabras, encuentra nuevas expresiones o simplemente practica el idioma, así que mantén un buen humor y respeta a los demás. **Si no estás de acuerdo con una respuesta, solo deja un comentario educado explicando tu queja** y que otros decidan quién tiene razón. OP siempre tendrá la última palabra.

Comment: I would also put commas, dots, colons... out of the counter, and just count letters.

Comment: I would specify that the Spanish variant can also be specified by the person asking. For example, if they mention Argentina, all words in the answers must have the same meaning in that country, so a Colombian specific word would not be accepted. And if no variant is allowed, it must be consistent: no country specific words unless they all are from the same one.

Comment: I have came up with an extra requirement: the person asking should provide an attempt himself, not to fool the system and disobey our current rules on showing the effort in translation questions.

Comment: @fedorqui well, in Code Golf the asker does not attempt to solve the problem, just presents the challenge. We could skip that rule in this case so that people do not get their attempts biased by the initial translation.

Comment: I see it as a safety filter. The problem here is that we would open a dangerous bias: people asking for _normal_ translations would have their questions closed if no previous attempt is shown, whereas people asking for _golf_ translations would be much welcomed. It would be a matter of days to have all these _normal_ translations to be tagged with [tag:translation-golf] so they can skip the rule.

Comment: @fedorqui that's a very good point indeed. Let's add that rule then.

Comment: I think that these questions should have their own tag. If we see this as a "game" (or game combined with learning activity) we may not need to enforce the some of the other rules to the letter, and maybe, just for "code-golf" questions, we don't need to ask for proof of previous research effort

Comment: @Diego I was thinking about a generic tag for "games" ("juegos") to tag every game-related question (we may come up with more games in the future), and a specific "translation-golf" tag for this game in particular. About the previous research effort, I agree with fedorqui, an initial translation should be given at least to have a starting point. That translation just show that you do not need the translation and you are just golfing, and can be a long one on purpose to give others the chance of playing.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo I think "juegos" could be ambiguous. Not that I can provide examples of questions that would need the tag "juegos" (maybe vocabulary about _parchís_? :-) ), but we have some pretty specific tags already. What about "Juegos-SpanisSE" to tell between a question about a game and a question that is posted as a game?

Comment: @Diego what if we leave "juegos" (plural) as a tag for questions about games, and create the tag "juego" (singular) to mark a specific question as a game?

Comment: What about translation of "you"?  Should we dictate in the question to use Vd/tú/vos?  Otherwise, I could get a huge boost in my old-fashionedy ones by using the second-person formal *él* ;-)

Comment: @guifa as long as it appears in the dictionary, it is valid. So "vd" is not valid, but the rest are. :-)

Comment: Following Jason C's suggestion, I vote for setting a limit of one of these questions per week.

Comment: @fedorqui done, a week will be the standard duration of a game (my initial proposal), and the winner sets the new game. Would you kindly modify the 48 hours-notice in your current question?

Comment: OK, done. I had thought there is no need to have an ongoing game at all times, hence the 48 hours to have some spare time in between. However, let's try it this way and see how it goes.

Comment: @fedorqui the new asker may ask his/her question inmediately after winning (a week after the previous question), or not. If not, after another 48 hours anyone can ask a new question, but that may or may not happen inmediately, so there is no need to have an ongoing game at any given time. Rules just say there can be only one (as a maximum) at any time. Anyway, in the best case we will have a game per week, so there will be no game-related question flooding.

Comment: I agree that is a good idea that a game winner has the privilege to start the new one, but if someone (intentionally or mistakenly) asks a new game - translation golf question without abiding these two rules (duration of a game; privilege of winner to start new game) should these questions be closed? They could of course be opened again when the conditions are right. I'm just asking because moderators should be prepared to _manually_ have a queue of these questions. Remember not everybody visits meta regularly and will know the fine print for the game rules.

Comment: @Diego not if every translation-golf question has a link to the rules and we encourage people to read them. If someone asks a new game question out of turn, we can encourage him/her to read the rules and to remove the question, saving it for when he/she wins a round. If it is not done so, the question is just removed. So the moderators do not need to maintain a question queue.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo - Since the game was your idea, could you make a couple of canned paragraphs to post at key times, for example: there are no dates shown on the Golf pages currently.  So could you post an update to the question two days or so before time runs out, and also post simple instructions to the person posting a game, and instructions for the person winning?  Also, I think there should be a date in the Question.  Finally, could you format the rules with numbers instead of bullets, so it's easier to cite a specific rule in the discussions?  Thanks.

Comment: @aparente001 Bullets to numbers, good idea. Done. But I'm not sure to understand what you mean with that "date" thing and the canned paragraphs. Could you possibly mean paragraphs to add to the post when the game is approaching its due date? Until now that has been done optionally by the OPs.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo - I was looking at this Meta page with all the rules, and was thinking that would be a convenient place to store some standard messages and some simple instructions for people who win and then post the next question.  To streamline things for people who don't want to read through a lot of comments. // Date suggestion: I don't see how to discern on what date a golf question was posted.

Comment: @aparente001 I have been thinking about what canned paragraphs we could use for the questions, but until now everone has posted them freely. You can add a new answer to this question with suggestions of canned texts if you think they might be useful. About the question date: in the question page you can see above to the right the message "asked X days ago". If you place the mouse cursor over that text, you get a tooltip with the exact moment the question was posted.

Comment: @Charlie: Rectifico, mea, culpa, no había leído bien la regla 3. Mea culpa ! Borro los comentarios al respecto

Comment: @yotanka acabo de editarla para que quedara más claro. :-)

Answer (score 6):

## Methods to easily count characters in a text

<sub>Please add here any method you find useful to count only the characters in a text, not counting puntuation marks, only letters [a-zA-Z] (including the accented ones) and digits [0-9], if any.</sub>

- With a console, store the file in say `/tmp/file.txt` and type the command:

  ```
  grep -o '[a-zA-Z0-9]' /tmp/file.txt | wc -l
  ```

  `grep -o` outputs the characters within the specified range, one per line. Then, `wc -l` (lowercase `L`) counts the lines. Check the locale, so that the range `a-zA-Z` includes the accented characters.
- As a bookmarklet with JavaScript.  Bookmark the following address and you can easily get a count with a simple click:
  `javascript:text=prompt("Introduce el texto para contar los golpes o letras.");result=text.replace(/[^a-záéíóúüýñ0-9]/uig,'');alert("Recuento de golpes: " + result.length + "\n\nTexto purificado:\n" + result);`
- Simpler bookmarklet, just shows the char count for whichever text you have selected: `javascript:alert(window.getSelection().toString().replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9áéíóúÁÉÍÓ‌​ÚüÜñÑ]/g,"").length);`. Tested in Chrome, Firefox and IE11 (Edge didn't let me create bookmarklets).

  [image]
- Visit [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ermv0rh/2/embedded/result/) (bookmark it), paste your text in the box, and read the character count from the bottom ([author](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2591/jason-c), if you run into any issues with it -- confirmed working on latest version of Firefox and Chrome as of March 2017):

  <kbd>[image]</kbd>

---

*Before adding a method here, please be sure to test its correctness. Here is a full test case (includes letters, digits, accented letters, punctuation and inverted punctuation, spaces, newlines, and an emoji), the character count should be 76:*

```
áéíóúüñ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
`~!@#$€%^&*()_+-={}|[]\:";'<>?,./¿¡☺
ÁÉÍÓÚÜÑ ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
0123456789
```

Comment: @JasonC I'm not sure why mine wouldn't.  By using the /u option, the regex should view a word like "qué" as q-u-e-´, and then would remove the ´.

Comment: @guifa It does not. I just tested it with http://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20246 and it reports 190. The correct count is 195. It could be related to localization options on the user's system, or ES6 support.

Comment: @JasonC Does SE use NFC or NFD?  (no one should be using NFC, but alas, it is maddeningly common)

Comment: @guifa AFAIK: It serves all text encoded as UTF-8, unmodified, exactly as entered, sometimes served as HTML entities (but without modification), and does not do any normalization, and normalization, if any, would be done by your browser on submit or presentation. (Sorry about the double-ping; I replaced my previous comment with one that has more of a disclaimer vibe... )

Comment: @guifa If you’re doing it right, then NFC vs NFD won’t matter. The easiest solution is `echo blahblahblah | perl -CS -nle 'print scalar(() = /\p{alnum}/g)'` which won’t care. That way Jason's cited answer yields 195 whether in NFC or NFD. Another approach is to parse out extended grapheme clusters each time (a base character plus optional combining characters), perhaps using the `\X` notation in a regex. And if we're code golfing, you can always shorten that to `perl -CS -nE'say$x=()=/\p{alnum}/g'` if it pleases you to do so. I suppose I should add these methods since they're easier.

Answer (score 4):

I originally posted this as a comment but it is probably worth being an answer:

I really think you guys at least ought to limit this to like one per week or something. If the [translation-golf](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation-golf)-to-other-question ratio becomes too high (which, it will -- everybody and their brother is going to want to post one of these), this beta runs a real risk of gaining a reputation as a translation service, which is not a recipe for a successful SE site.

Also, as an aside, you may want to make sure they are CW (community wiki) to avoid rep inflation for content that is orthogonal to the site's real purpose (presuming its real purpose *isn't* a creative translation service), especially if some of these end up on the HNQ.

I'd also consider giving a possible time limit to these and then locking them after that time limit, but you might want to just see how it goes for a while before determining if that's necessary or not.

I think it sounds like a fun idea. I think it can also do a lot of damage if not properly managed.

Comment: Perhaps we could do this like in the PCG — have a proposal for them initially on Meta, and then a site admin could release one every so often.

Comment: I have added a guideline about there being only one active question about translation-golf at any given time. About making the answers CW, I find it a good idea, but how can we make the questions also CW?

Comment: @CarlosAlejo Users can't do it, a moderator must. So you may post the question then raise a custom flag requesting a CW conversion. After that all answers will automatically be CW. If this becomes generally acceptable, I'd also expect mods to monitor the tag and convert as they see new posts.

Comment: @JasonC sounds fine. Added to the rules.

Comment: Very good points, Jason C. I am in for the week limit to one question. Regarding this being a translation service, we added the rule that the OP has to offer their own translation, so that people does not use it as that. Converting to CW in 3, 2, 1...

Comment: In my question I gave 48 hours to set the winner, but I also consider that users may came up with better approaches in the future, only that the winner would not change. Since you are very active in [codegolf.se], what benefits do you see in locking the posts after that given time?

Comment: @fedorqui To lock or not comes down to whether or not you want to allow new answers (and home page bumps) a year after the challenge is posted (for example). It's not really a strong "recommendation", I just thought I'd mention it, and actually, on PPCG some really interesting stuff comes late some times. But really at this early stage, and given that you're trying to promote site activity, probably doesn't make sense to lock them. It'd be something to revisit later.

Comment: @fedorqui and Jason, of course: according to the Area 51 stats, the site received 3.5 questions per day in the last two weeks. I have counted 30 new questions in between the two first translation-golf questions, that makes 4.3 questions per day in the last week (not counting the golfing questions). Still soon to say it, but that means that in the previous week we had only received 2.7 questions per day ((2.7 + 4.3) / 2 = 3.5). I have noticed indeed a considerable increase in the numbers of questions asked, so maybe the game is doing its job: to promote the site.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo [Here is a graph of activity on this site in the past year (number of questions asked, answers posted, and up/down votes made).](http://data.stackexchange.com/spanish/query/653045/daily-site-activity-graph?Days=365&VScale=7&WindowSize=6#graph). You may adjust the window size accordingly. If "Votes" is annoying set VScale really high, like 1000 or something, to get it out of the way. A few observations about that in the next comment...

Comment: @CarlosAlejo Overall I'd say there isn't enough info either way. 2 weeks isn't really enough time to notice a trend, and the noise is consistent with what it has been over the past year. However this site is definitely better than it was last April (activity tends to vary on yearly cycles, e.g. December is low, etc.), you can see it if you increase the time range to 400 days or so. Also if you set the window size high (like 30 days or more) you can see a *generally* increasing trend in site usage (a good thing). So let it run for a few more months, then check again.

Comment: cc @fedorqui ^^^

Comment: Jason: I guess your numbers come from this interesting SEDE query of yours [Daily Site Activity Graphs with Sliding Average (Smoothing)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/293286/209901) I like them better than the ones I used on [this post](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2490/1674), where I was counting by weeks. cc @CarlosAlejo

Comment: .....What's CW?

Comment: @aparente001 Community wiki.

Answer (score 2):

Completed games

### 2017

1. Mar 27 → Apr 2: [Let translation-golf begin: Fragmento de "Breakfast at Tiffany's" sobre los miedos del personaje principal](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/20241/let-translation-golf-begin-fragmento-de-breakfast-at-tiffanys-sobre-los-mied) (proposed by fedorqui)

   1. [**Carlos Alejo**](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20242/1674) → 116 characters
   2. [guifa](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20250/1674) → 118
   3. [Astrar](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20255/1674) → 159
2. Apr 3 → Apr 10: [Translation-golf and the SOLID principles](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/20346/translation-golf-and-the-solid-principles) (Carlos Alejo)

   1. [**Ixi**](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20409/1674) → 205 characters
   2. [fedorqui](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20347/1674) → 222
   3. [Laski](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20364/1674) → 223
3. Apr 12 → Apr 20: [How to translate-golf the introduction of "I Have a Dream" by Martin Luther King?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/20488/how-to-translate-golf-the-introduction-of-i-have-a-dream-by-martin-luther-king) (fedorqui)

   1. [**Carlos Alejo**](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20491/1674) → 70 characters
   2. [rsanchez](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20494/1674) → 81
   3. [Diego](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20490/1674) → 92
4. Apr 20 → Apr 27: [Translation-golf of the greatest and most famous spoiler in movie history](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/20609/translation-golf-of-the-greatest-and-most-famous-spoiler-in-movie-history) (Carlos Alejo)

   1. [**aparente001**](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20617/1674) → 135 characters
   2. [Diego](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20615/1674) → 151
   3. [fedorqui](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20610/1674) → 162
5. May 1 → May 10: [Translation Golf: “Car Talk” Excerpt for some fun](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/20732/5481) (aparente001)

   1. [**Diego**](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20789/5481) → 344 characters
   2. [Carlos Alejo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20745/5481) → 347
   3. [fedorqui](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20783/5481) → 426
   4. Mención especial: [aparente001](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20858/5481) → 341
6. May 10 → May 17: [Translation-golf VI: Sandkings by George R. R. Martin](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/20863/5481) (Diego)

   1. [**walen**](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20876/5481) → 235 caracteres
   2. [Carlos Alejo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20867/5481) → 248
   3. [aparente001](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20871/5481) → 280
   4. [fedorqui](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20864/5481) → 283
   5. Mención especial: fuera de concurso walen recopila las mejores ideas de cada respuesta en [una única entrada](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20953/5481), consiguiendo una propuesta de traducción de tan **solo 211 caracteres**.
7. May 18 → May 25 [Translation-golf VII: “Lose yourself” by Eminem](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/20968/1674) (walen).

   1. [**CarlosAlejo**](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20976/13628) → 166 caracteres. (*Victoria _cum laude_ además, ya que ha conseguido mantener la rima original :-O ¡Mi enhorabuena!*)
   2. [aparente001](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20981/13628) → 179
   3. [Diego](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20969/13628) → 216
   4. [dockeryZ](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/21015/13628) → 307
8. May 25 → Jun 2 [Translation-golf VIII: with a twist](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/21045/1674) (Carlos Alejo).

   1. [**walen**](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/21061/1674) → 161 caracteres.
   2. [fedorqui](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/21051/1674) → 176
   3. [user135711](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/21047/1674) → 186
   4. [Carlos Alejo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/21052/1674) → 201
   5. [JMVanPelt](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/21147/1674) → 237
9. June 12 → Jun 19 [Translation-golf IX: V's introduction](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/21194/5481) (Diego).

   1. **[JMVanPelt](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/21231/5481)** → 287 caracteres.
   2. [Carlos Alejo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/21200/5481) → 298

Answer (score 1):

#### 2017 Christmas Special Edition Rules

- Game duration: **the game starts Tuesday, December 19th 2017 and ends Monday, January 8th 2018** (about 3 weeks duration).
- Proposed text: https://americanliterature.com/childrens-stories/twas-the-night-before-christmas
- Participants: whoever wants to join, **OP included**.
- Game modes: there'll be **two categories: Prose and Rhyme**.
- **Prose Rules**: the usual rules apply.
- **Rhyme Rules**:

  - **Keep line count (56) and verse count (14)**.
  - **Keep the rhyme structure**, which is **AABB** inside each verse (rhyme can change from one verse to the next).
  - Bonuses:

    - Rhyme bonus: **5% for an *asonante* rhyme, 10% for a *consonante* rhyme**. [Info about rhyme in Spanish](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rima).
    - Metre bonus: **5% for a uniform metre verse-wise, 10% for a uniform metre poem-wise**.
    - **Bonuses are added together first** (máx bonus 20%) and total bonus is applied as a reduction over the proposed answer's length, rounding up.

      - Example: an answer of 197 chars, with a 5% asonante bonus and 5% verse-wise metre bonus, get a 10% total bonus. Its effective char count would be 197 - 10% = 177,3 ≈ **178**.
- **Answers** per participant:

  - Any given participant can post **máx one (1) Prose answer and max one (1) Rhyme answer**.
  - Each answer must **name the category** it is participating in, and propose **one translation only**, also including the **char count without bonus**. Bonuses will be taken into account by OP as needed (to avoid confusing errors and long lines of strike-through'd numbers ;).
  - **Mixed answers are not allowed** (one answer with two or more translations, whatever the category).
- Choosing the winning answers:

  - The winning answer in each category will be that which, once **validated by OP** and with all bonuses applied, gets **the shortest translation** in said category, no matter the author.
  - Since it is not possible to mark two answers as accepted, at the end of the game OP will post and accept a new answer declaring the winners.
- **Prizes**:

  - **"Manco de Lepanto"**: **50 rep bounty** awarded to the winning answer in the Prose category.
  - **"Naricísimo Infinito"**: **50 rep bounty** awarded to the winning answer in the Rhyme category.
  - **"Fénix de los Ingenios"**: in the event that the same participant is the author of both winning answers, **on top of the aforementioned bounties, they get the right to post the next Translation Golf text** once this special edition is over.

Along with the above, all the usual rules apply, as long as they don't conflict with the ones in here.

---

#### Reglas especiales de la Edición Especial de Navidad 2017

- Duración del juego: **el juego comenzará el martes, 19 de diciembre de 2017 y terminará el lunes, 8 de enero de 2018** (unas 3 semanas de duración).
- Texto propuesto: https://americanliterature.com/childrens-stories/twas-the-night-before-christmas
- Participantes: quien quiera, **incluido OP**.
- Modos de juego: habrá **dos categorías: Prosa y Rima**.
- **Reglas para Prosa**: aplican las reglas habituales.
- **Reglas para Rima**:

  - **Mantener el número de versos (56) y estrofas (14)**.
  - **Mantener la estructura de rima**, que es **AABB** dentro de cada estrofa (de una estrofa a otra es indiferente).
  - Bonus aplicables:

    - Por rima: **5% por rima asonante y 10% por rima consonante**.
    - Por métrica: **5% por métrica uniforme a nivel de estrofa, y 10% por mantener la misma métrica en todo el poema**.
    - **Los bonus se suman antes de aplicarse** (bonus máximo 20%) y el bonus total se aplica como reducción sobre el conteo de la traducción propuesta, redondeando hacia arriba.

      - Ejemplo: una respuesta de 197 caracteres con los bonus de 5% por asonante y 5% por métrica a nivel de estrofa, obtiene un bonus del 10%. Su conteo efectivo será 197 - 10% = 177,3 ≈ **178**.
- **Respuestas** por participante:

  - Un mismo participante podrá publicar como **máximo una (1) respuesta en Prosa y máximo una (1) respuesta en Rima**.
  - Cada respuesta debe **indicar la categoría** en que participa y proponer **una única traducción**, incluyendo también el **conteo sin aplicar los bonus**. De los cálculos ya se encarga OP (para evitar errores que confundan a los demás y también esas ristras interminables de números tachados ;).
  - **No se admiten respuestas mixtas** (una misma respuesta con dos o más traducciones, sean de la misma o distinta categoría).
- Elección de respuestas ganadoras:

  - La respuesta ganadora de cada categoría será la que, siendo **considerada válida** por OP y tras aplicar los bonus correspondientes, consiga **la traducción más corta** en esa categoría, sin importar el autor.
  - Dado que no se pueden marcar dos respuestas aceptadas, al final del juego OP publicará y aceptará una nueva respuesta indicando las ganadoras.
- **Premios**:

  - **Premio "Manco de Lepanto"**: **recompensa de 50 puntos** de reputación para la respuesta ganadora de la **categoría Prosa**.
  - **Premio "Naricísimo Infinito"**: **recompensa de 50 puntos** de reputación para la respuesta vencedora en la **categoría Poesía**.
  - **Premio "Fénix de los Ingenios"**: en el caso de que un mismo participante sea el autor de las respuestas ganadoras en ambas categorías, **además de las recompensas mencionadas, obtendrá el derecho a proponer el texto del siguiente Translation Golf**, una vez finalizada esta edición especial.

Además de lo anterior, aplican todas las reglas habituales, siempre que no entren en conflicto con lo aquí indicado.