# Need help formatting hidden text

Tags: soporte, formato

In my [translation golf question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/20732/9385), I couldn't get separate paragraphs to be hidden (until mouseover) with the markdown >! -- I had to run the paragraphs together to get it to work.  Hope someone will edit my question, fix it, and explain how they got it to work right.

Comment: Seems like a bug worth reporting on meta.stackexchange.com.  Also, why do you need to hide that text? :)

Comment: @Flimzy we [agreed](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2592/1674) on making translation-golf questions include a dummy translation to fulfill the requirement of "show your attempts first".

Comment: @fedorqui Ah, fair enough.

Comment: @Flimzy and the part about hiding is because [aparente001](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/20241/let-translation-golf-begin-fragmento-de-breakfast-at-tiffanys-sobre-los-mied#comment30680_20241) mentioned that _It takes too much effort to ignore the first version when it's sitting right there on the screen, right below the original_. So hiding it seems to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now it is not possible to have multi-line spoilers using normal paragraphs:

```
>! This is something.

>! And this is another thing.
```

does not render as a spoiler, but rather as:

> ! This is something.
>
> ! And this is another thing.

However, you can trick it a bit and get a new spoiler line by inserting the spoiler markdown plus two spaces (`>!`).  To get a blank line between paragraphs, do that twice.  To show you how to do this, I will use another trick, and insert four blanks at the beginning of each line, to make it visible:

```
>! Paragraph 1
>!                # (this line contains two trailing spaces)
>!                # (this line contains two trailing spaces)
>! Paragraph 2
```

The result:

> this is something
>
>
>  I want to hide

It is not the perfect solution, since it does not group in paragraphs but in `<br />`-like format. But it is at least better.

See [What's the exact syntax for spoiler markup](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/72878/209901) for an explanation on how it works by the DEV who implemented it:

> The way the spoiler works is as follows.
>
> If each line in a `blockquote` (built via `>`) begins with a `!`, it
>   will be treated as a spoiler.

Also see [How to do multi-line spoilers properly?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/285029/209901) for the trick I revealed above.

Alternatively, you can insert `<br>` in your stream of text, wherever you would like a paragraph separation to occur.

Comment: This is great.  I think for me the easiest thing will usually be to just insert the `<br>` where I want the separation.  But if I have a lot of text, the `>! space space` approach will be preferable so I can see my text clearly while composing.