# Glosario de términos usados en el sitio / Glossary of frequently used terms in this site

Tags: discusión, faq

Con frecuencia usamos siglas, acrónimos y similares en el sitio. Los usuarios más activos o veteranos suelen conocerlos, pero puede que el resto de gente no.

Por ello, incluyamos los términos más comunes para facilitar la comprensión de nuestras publicaciones.

---

We quite often use initials, acronyms and other contractions to express concepts and terms commonly used in Stack Exchange. They are well known by active or regular users, but others may not know them.

So let's collect them in a list so that nobody feels puzzled when reading our posts :)

Also interesting: [Stack Exchange Glossary - Dictionary of Commonly-Used Terms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/40353/209901)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- **[ASALE](https://www.asale.org/)**: Asociación de Academias de la Lengua Española. A higher entity that encompasses the RAE and other academies.
- [**BNE**](http://www.bne.es): Biblioteca Nacional de España. It is the home of a very interesting resource: its [newspaper library](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/index.vm).
- [**CORDE**](http://corpus.rae.es/cordenet.html): Corpus Diacrónico del Español. A corpus of the written Spanish from its beginnings until 1974.
- [**CORPES**](http://web.frl.es/CORPES/view/inicioExterno.view):  Corpus del Español del Siglo XXI. A corpus of the written Spanish with texts from 2001 until 2012.
- [**CREA**](http://corpus.rae.es/creanet.html): Corpus de Referencia del Español Actual. A corpus of the written Spanish with texts from 1975 until 2004.
- [**DAMER**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/): Diccionario de Americanismos. A dictionary with the words and expressions used in Latin America.
- [**DIRAE**](http://dirae.es/): inverse dictionary where you can find a Spanish word provided that you know its meaning.
- [**DLE**](http://dle.rae.es/): Diccionario de la lengua española.
- **DRAE**: Diccionario de la RAE. Used indistinctly with "DLE" (see above), though DLE is preferred.
- [**DPD**](http://www.rae.es/recursos/diccionarios/dpd): Diccionario panhispánico de dudas. Gives answers to the most habitual linguistic doubts (orthographic, lexical and grammatical) of Spanish.
- [**NTLLE**](http://ntlle.rae.es/ntlle/SrvltGUILoginNtlle): Nuevo tesoro lexicográfico de la lengua española. A dictionary of dictionaries (both monolingual and bilingual) that compiles a wide selection of works that define the lexical heritage of the Spanish language, and covering the last 500 years.
- [**RAE**](http://www.rae.es/): Real Academia Española.

---

- **CW**: [Community Wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/209901). A post intended to be edited and enhanced by all users, not giving rep to any user in particular.
- **TG**: a reference to the [translation-golf](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation-golf) tag. See [This is translation-golf! The translation with the least number of characters wins!](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2591/1674).