# ¿Se debe permitir usar números en las respuestas a los translation-golf si el original no los tiene?

Tags: discusión, juegos

En algunas ediciones del [translation-golf](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation-golf), el texto original tiene referencias a números, expresadas en algunos casos con cifras y en otros con letras. Por poner un ejemplo, en [la edición XIV](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/21724/12637) el texto a traducir contenía un número en cifras:

> *E nella camera 200 note*

y en las traducciones nadie lo expresó de ninguna otra forma. A fin de cuentas, "200" ya tiene muy pocos caracteres y no necesita ser reducido más. Pero en otras ediciones, los textos sí contienen referencias a cantidades expresadas con letras:

> *...six-limbed, with six tiny eyes set all around its body...*

[En aquella ocasión](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/20863/12637) pareció que todos respetaron aquello y en las traducciones propuestas pone "seis". Sin embargo, en otras ediciones han salido [textos como este](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22308/12637):

> *...and a hundred baby spiders came out...*

y las traducciones mencionaban "cien" hasta que alguien propuso "100" y se abrió el debate sobre si se debía permitir eso o no. Así pues, debatamos correctamente para ver si modificamos [las reglas de los *translation-golf*](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2592/12637) o no:

**¿Se debe permitir usar números en las respuestas a los translation-golf si el original no los tiene?**

Answer (score 2):

## No

Se debe respetar el original si este ha decidido no usar números. Además, si todo el mundo usa números se pierde la competitividad al dejarse de buscar sinónimos o expresiones equivalentes escritas con letras (ejemplo: "doscientas treinta y siete" por "más de doscientas"). Si todos escribieran "237" no tendría gracia.

[Añadir más razones si se considera oportuno.]

Comment: No puedo votar mi propio post, pero contad con mi +1 en esta respuesta. :-P

Comment: `Si todos escribieran "237" no tendría gracia.` Es lo que intento conseguir de otra manera con la ídea de normalizar los números.

Comment: @walen por supuesto, no te lo niego y a la larga seguramente tendremos ese problema, pero es algo que surgirá con el tiempo y tras muchas ediciones, la gente irá aprendiendo cuáles son las palabras más cortas en cada caso. No les hagamos la vida más fácil permitiendo números, ya que es una transformación que, de aprobarse, se hará desde el primer momento y todos por igual para cualquier número que aparezca.

Answer (score 1):

## Irrelevante

Esta decisión se debe dejar al criterio de cada pregunta. Debe ser el OP quien especifique en cada caso si se permite o no.

Comment: Es un recurso válido y bastante creativo, aunque como el resto de la traducción, es el OP quien decide. Eso si, debe decidirlo al plantear el reto.

Answer (score 0):

## Sí

Razones:

- A fin de cuentas, **el objetivo es realizar la traducción con el menor número de caracteres posibles (sean números o letras)**. Si la forma de conseguir esto es usando números, se debería poder permitir.
- De todos los posibles para golfear una traducción, **este es el único recurso que respeta al 100% el original en cuanto a cifras exactas**, como edades, años o cantidades. En la edición anterior, todos los participantes optaron por cambiar "decenas de miles" por "miles", incluso la [respuesta ganadora](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/22078/13628) optó por "mil". Si aceptamos un cambio como ese, ¿por qué no íbamos a aceptar "más de 10 000" que mantiene el sentido mucho más fielmente?
- El uso de cifras para escribir números **es gramaticalmente correcto**. La RAE [*recomienda*](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=QHaq7I8KrD6FQAyXTS) usar letras para cantidades menores que 100, pero se permite el uso de cifras también. De hecho, el único criterio para lo contrario es el de "elegancia", que estaremos de acuerdo en que no aplica para un juego como este.
- **No es un "recurso fácil". Hay varios casos en que no se puede aplicar.** No lo puedes aplicar a cantidades en plural: no puedes cambiar "cientos" por "100" sin justificarlo, tendrías que poner "más de 100" y sales perdiendo. No lo puedes aplicar a artículos indeterminados: no puedes cambiar "un día ganaré el juego" por "1 día ganaré el juego" (pero tal vez sí "dame una razón" por "dame 1 razón"). Seguramente haya más casos, pero esos bastan para comprobar que incluso para usar cifras hay que darle una pensada antes.

[Añadir más razones si se considera oportuno.]

Comment: No veo porque no usar números en cifras siempre que se respeten las normas sobre números de la RAE. Tampoco creo que haya muchas posibilidades ni den demasiado juego las variaciones que podrían encontrarse usando únicamente palabras. Por eso voto que si.

Answer (score 0):

## Si, pero deben ser normalizados

Hay casos en que los números parecen mejores y otros en que no lo parecen. Por ejemplo `T-101` vs `T-ciento uno` y `morirán mil` vs `moriran 1000`. La pregunta de cómo se escriben números no debería influir en los puntos. Una manera de garantizarlo sería cambiar números en letras antes de contarlas. Hay casos en que los números parecen mejores y otros en que no lo parecen. Por ejemplo `T-101` vs `T-ciento uno` y `Somos cinco.` vs `Somos 5.`.

Por ejemplo antes de contar las letras `Había 2000 maneras de hacerlo.` se cambiaría en `Había dos mil maneras de hacerlo.`

Comment: ¿Esto no es lo mismo que la respuesta del "no"? A fin de cuentas, dices que antes de contar los caracteres se cambien los números por texto... En todo caso, ten en cuenta que el debate sobre cómo normalizar los números vendrá más adelante, si sale adelante la respuesta del "sí".

Comment: No exactamente: da a los jugadores la elección de escribir la forma que los parece las más natural sin penalizarlos. Y permite que casos como `T-101` o la famosa eror `ID-10-T` se traduzcan de una manera más clara. EDIT: Y voto `no` no podiendo votar mi propio post, pienso que intenta cumplir la misma idea.

Comment: Si al contar los caracteres estás cambiando "2000" por "dos mil" sí los penalizas, dado que ellos esperan cuatro caracteres y al final cuentan seis.

Comment: No en el sentido que los hace iguales con quienquira escribe "dos mil": no hay una manera más eficaz. Sería igualmente posible normalizar "dos mil" en "2000", pero sería necesario también normalizar "un / una" en "1", lo que no es el óptimo.

Comment: Pero entonces estás defendiendo la postura del "no", no hacía falta escribir una opción nueva. Se espera que quien escribe "2000" se le cuentan cuatro caracteres y quien escribe "dos mil" se le cuenten seis, y quede a elección de cada uno usar números o letras. No hablamos de hacer cambios automáticos, ya que supone un problema para el JSFiddle que cuenta los caracteres.

Comment: Estoy defendiendo lo que el no quiere cumplir, pero de una manera - siguiendo mi razonamiento - más eficaz. Quizás un comentario con el no hubiera sido mejor, te lo acuerdo.

Comment: No es lo que quiero decir; si, y lo siento si es el caso, la respuesta tiene erores de Español, son lás mias (y si alguien puede corregirlas, sería super). Lo que quiero cumplir es a un lado permitir los números si un jugador piensa que el estilo es mejor y al otro lado no penalizar una forma de escribirlos (con letras) versus la otra (con números)

Comment: Me parece razonable. Voy a copiar lo que he dicho en la Tertulia: `Quizás no debería tomar parte en eso; las reglas (o consejos) para escribir números no son las mismas en Finés y en español. Para mi escribir 2000 me parece muy raro.`