# Un posible Alphabetic-golf

Tags: discusión, juegos

Quisiera proponer para abril una especie de 'Alphabetic-golf'. Sería un escrito de un máximo de 26 palabras. El juego  consistiría en escribir un relato, un párrafo, poema o entremés (muy difícil lo último, pero conociendo quienes escriben, no es imposible) que tenga una y solo una palabra que empiece con cada una de las letras del español.

Sería posible dejar abierta la puerta de usar menos palabras (si se hace difícil) pero en ese caso, a cambio de cada letra faltante se le sumarían las letras de la palabra más larga del español (según tengo entendido, según el DLE es *Electroencefalografista* ). Para la explicación de los castigos usemos [cuentos cortos en español](https://forodeespanol.com/Archive/ElCuentoMasCortoDelMundo/dkl/post.htm) (modificados para que cumplan las reglas) si Monterroso hubiera mandado una adaptación del dinosaurio, de la siguiente forma:

> *Y* *c*uando *s*e *l*evantó, *e*l *d*inosaurio *t*odavía *p*ersistía *a*hí.

El escrito tendría 47 letras, pero solo utiliza como letras iniciales: Y, C, S, L, E, D, T, P y A, lo que lleva como castigo las 17 letras que dejó de usar, así que tendríamos que ponerle 17 * 23 (las letras que tiene la palabra más larga) = 391 letras, y le sumamos las letras del escrito, su escrito tendría 438 letras.

Ahora, si participa el emigrante, de Lomelí, quedaría así

> ¿*O*lvida *u*sted *a*lgo? *q*uiera *D*ios

Usa solo 5 letras (O, U, A, Q y D), así que al relato de 25 caracteres le sumariamos 21 letras que no se usan (21 * 23 = 483 letras) quedaría de 504 letras.

Las versiones originales de estos cuentos no valdrían pues repiten letras ( cuando *d*espertó, *e*l *d*inosaurio todavía *e*staba ahí y ¿*O*lvida usted algo? *O*jalá). Se aplicarían las últimas 7 reglas del [translation-golf](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2591/this-is-translation-golf-the-translation-with-the-least-number-of-characters-wi/2592#2592) (de la 5 a la 12).

Si se logra hacer que el escrito vaya en orden alfabético (la primera palabra empieza con A, la segunda con B... y la última empieza con Z), se dejaría un 10 % de rebaja (usando todas las letras, sin que falte alguna).

Si les llama la atención o no lo consideran 'necesario', se los planteo para este mes.

Al revisar el comentario de @yotanka, en [esta pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/14999/frases-en-espa%C3%B1ol-que-usan-palabras-que-empiezan-todas-sucesivamente-por-a-b-c) sugerían un juego similar, con ciertos comportamientos para la longitud de palabras. Como explico en el comentario, sería de escribir el abecegrama más corto posible (en lo posible con un mínimo de sentido)

¡Pásenla bien!

Comment: Traté de componer "se levantarse" pero no sé si capté bien tu idea.  Chequeas, por favor....

Comment: Se oye muy divertido pero no sé si entendí bien bien todas las reglas.  Quizás un fragmento de ejemplo ayudaría.

Comment: Kinda related: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/14993/hay-frases-en-espa%C3%B1ol-que-usen-todas-las-letras-de-una-vez and https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/2028/quick-brown-fox-equivalent-in-spanish/2029#2029

Comment: Definetely related: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/14999/frases-en-espa%C3%B1ol-que-usan-palabras-que-empiezan-todas-sucesivamente-por-a-b-c

Comment: thanks for the comment @yotanka. The idea is publish the shortest *abecegrama* in this month.

Comment: el comentario de @walen me pone a pensar un poco... y pensé que tocaba quitar la primera definición de las letras, pero viendo el dle... por ejemplo menciona que en español q siempre viene en dígrafo *qu*. Lo dejaría a elección si se eliminan esa primera definición de cada letra (*posicion* letra del abecedario español, que representa al  fonema ...), con las reglas antes mencionadas