# ¿Deberíamos pasar los juegos a Meta?

Tags: discusión

Ahora que el *Translation Golf* lleva camino de 40 ediciones, y que se están proponiendo [nuevos juegos](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2878/12637), me estoy dando cuenta de que el sitio principal tal vez no sea el mejor sitio para que los juegos tengan lugar. A fin de cuentas, los juegos no son preguntas sobre el idioma español propiamente dichas. Tampoco estoy seguro de si meta es el mejor lugar, dado que los juegos tampoco son preguntas sobre el sitio.

En todo caso, planteo la cuestión y explico otras razones:

- Las preguntas que planteen juegos no deben generar puntos de reputación. Esto ya pasa en meta: aquí plantear una pregunta no genera puntos, y las medallas que se consigan quedan en meta y no afectan al conteo del sitio general.
- A la edición actual de cada juego se puede solicitar que se le ponga el tag *featured* para darle visibilidad desde el sitio principal, aunque a pocos votos que se le den a la pregunta, esta aparecerá como "hot meta post". En ambos casos los juegos se publicitarán y la gente no perderá el compás de las ediciones en curso.
- No invadimos el sitio principal con preguntas que pueden no interesar a algunos, al tiempo que atraemos la atención hacia meta para darle un poco más de vida a este sitio paralelo. Esto puede ser especialmente relevante si se nos van ocurriendo más juegos: podríamos vernos en la situación de que la mayoría de las preguntas que se planteen sean de juegos.

Problemas:

- No estoy seguro de si las preguntas CW aparecen o no en las HNQ (no me queda claro). Si es así, perderíamos la opción de aparecer en dicha lista con las preguntas del TG, aunque sinceramente, tampoco creo que las preguntas del TG deban aparecer en dicha lista dado que, insisto, son juegos, no preguntas.

En fin, dejo el debate abierto a ver qué opináis.

Comment: @walen por supuesto. No pretendo que esto sea una propuesta a la que votar positivo si se está de acuerdo o negativo en caso contrario. Solo quería iniciar un debate sobre el tema para ver qué opináis. Queda claro que no tengo en la cabeza todos los pros y contras y por eso básicamente pido vuestra ayuda y opinión.

Comment: Si puedo luego amplío con una respuesta. Yo coincido en el el sitio principal no es el mejor lugar para los juegos, pero creo que Meta es menos apropiado. Los juego son algo artificial dentro del stack, salvo que seas uno de esos stacks de Puzzles y juegos o codegolf. Yo prefiero tener meta para discutir sobre el sitio. El translation golf dentro de lo que cabe no deja de ser una pregunta (es traducción + "cuál es la forma más breve de redactar esto?") con la que aprendemos, y ya hemos acordado ciertas medidas de precaución como hacerlas wiki y no tener más de uno por semana.

Comment: Coincido con @Diego: la parte Meta del sitio es para cosas _sobre_ el sitio. Mejor que esté tranquila :)

Comment: creo que voy con quienes ya han respondido u opinado, no los veo en meta, aunque me parece que antes de publicar el juego en el sitio, debe pasar por un filtro por acá (una breve explicación), para evitar que queden como off-topic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recordemos que los beneficios de juegos como este, y por tanto el sentido de permitirlos, eran:

- Atraer usuarios.
- Favorecer que suba el ratio de respuestas por pregunta.
- Pasar un buen rato :)

Si movemos los juegos a Meta, perdemos los dos primeros beneficios:

- Los posts de Meta no salen en las HNQ (que yo sepa), por tanto no vendrán nuevos usuarios.
- Las respuestas al juego dejarán de contar para el ratio del sitio principal.

Anécdota: si yo estoy hoy aquí participando en el sitio, es porque un día vi el TG de Sandkings en las HNQ. Comprenderéis entonces que a nivel personal me parezca relevante que estos juegos puedan salir en esa lista global.
Sí, el juego seguramente aparecería en el panel de Hot Meta Questions, pero eso ya sería a nivel local del sitio, no global de todo SE. Sólo lo veríamos los de siempre. Y aparte, le robaría sitio a otros posts más propios de Meta que quizá sean más importantes (el número de posts mostrados es limitado), así que no sé si convendría tenerlos como "featured".

En cuanto a la diversión, la podemos tener igual en Meta... en principio. Porque si el juego deja de ser tan visible, al final jugaremos siempre los mismos, nos cansaremos y terminaremos por abandonarlo (ya hemos estado a punto de hacerlo alguna vez, y si no lo hicimos fue gracias a que entró gente nueva o que no participa tanto).

Eso por la parte de los inconvenientes.
¿Cuáles serían las ventajas?

- Quitar de la página principal una pregunta —dos, si sale adelante algún otro juego— que a lo mejor no interesa a algún usuario. ¿A todo el mundo le interesan las otras 49 preguntas, siempre? Yo no lo creo.
- Atraer más tráfico a Meta. Discutible por lo dicho antes (vendríamos solo los de siempre). Que hubiera más participación en Meta sería beneficioso, sin duda, pero sinceramente creo que si la gente no participa en Meta no es porque no sepan que Meta existe, sino porque no les interesa participar de esa manera en la comunidad (y están en su derecho). Y si no les interesa ahora, no va a hacerlo tampoco por poner el juego en Meta. Incluso, dado el poco tráfico de preguntas de Meta, podría ser perjudicial mover los juegos porque aquí sí podría darse el caso (imposible en el sitio principal) de que las preguntas de los juegos estén siempre las primeras, robando toda la atención.

¿Merece la pena perder los beneficios y vidilla que nos dan estos juegos, por algo así?

En mi opinión, no.