# What's a kosher way of switching to the community wiki approach?

Tags: discusión, soporte, respuestas-wiki

Let's say there's a question that gets several answers, but I think the question lends itself to being *community wiki*.  Do I have to post at Meta, or is there some more direct way of switching the approach on that page to a single answer under the community wiki format?

Example: [Are there verbs where the lexical root of the perfect tense forms differs from that of its infinitive form?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/30392/9385)

Comment: Here is the basic information on community wiki posts. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts

Comment: @Lambie - Thanks.  Apparently I can raise a flag for moderator attention, to request that an answer be converted.

Comment: @walen - How about putting this in an answer?  I like the idea and am thinking of giving that a try next time, i.e. starting an answer stub myself when I post the question, in the first place.  (Maybe take out the part about blaming?  I have a teenager at home -- I already get a lot of blame on a daily basis.)

Comment: @walen - Well, to me it's a solution.  I was asking in general, and I gave an example so people could see why I was asking for help.

Answer (score 1):

As Lambie mentioned in comments, questions can just be converted into Community Wiki by moderators, so you need to flag them or open a Meta post to request it.

Prior to 2014 the CW status was set automatically under some circumstances (a lot of edits by the OP / different users, many answers...) but [it was finally changed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228940/209901). There is a relevant reading: this blog post by the community manager who changed this: [Putting the Community back in Wiki](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/04/22/putting-the-community-back-in-wiki/).

In general I don't think there is any need to convert questions to Community Wiki. [We have exactly 46](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq%20wiki%3Ayes):

- 44 from the [translation-golf](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation-golf), which was a decision we made to avoid this game generating reputation to the users (see rules in [This is translation-golf! The translation with the least number of characters wins!](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2591/1674)).
- [Are there any words that have opposite regional meanings?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/324/1674) an old question, which I myself would see better as not-CW.
- [Resources for learning Spanish / Recursos para aprender español](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/23617/1674) a new one that needs to be easily editable by users, no matter how much reputation they have.

So the baseline would be: if a question is going to need a lot of attention by a lot of users and works as a Wiki itself, let's mark it as so. Otherwise, just leave the ownership as is.