# Charlie's Greatest Hits

Tags: discusión, preguntas, respuestas

What are some of our chillin' champion [Charlie](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/users/12637/charlie)'s greatest hits?  Could be a question or an answer (or both!).

Give us a link and a quote.  Include your name and optionally tell us why it grabbed you.

[image: Charlie]

Comment: Check it out: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/328835/287826

Answer (score 6):

- [¿Por qué decimos "apropiar" (sin r) y no "apropriar" si viene del latín "appropriāre"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/18012/por-qu%c3%a9-decimos-apropiar-sin-r-y-no-apropriar-si-viene-del-lat%c3%adn-appropr/18015?r=SearchResults&s=3|3.0202#18015) (aparente001: I have always been confused about *apropriado* and *apropiado*.)

  > dejar caer letras para darle más suavidad al idioma
- [Etymologically, why do "ser" and "estar" exist?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/18441/12637)
  (Charlie: I am particularly proud of my answer to this question, although it's just a personal favourite of mine.)
- [Etimología de "tiovivo"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/28585/12637)
  [¿Cuál es el origen de la expresión “dar para el pelo”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/22085/12637)
  (Charlie: These two questions got their answers from the Spain National Library, and I think the two stories are quite amusing, specially the second one.)
- [This is translation-golf! The translation with the least number of characters wins!](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2591)
  (walen) La pregunta de Meta en la que Charlie propuso hacer un juego llamado "Translation-Golf". Una iniciativa que consiguió atraer y enganchar a varios usuarios, un juego que ha echado por tierra el mito de que los textos siempre quedan más largos en español, que nos ha enseñado a retorcer y moldear el idioma hasta límites insospechados... ¡Gracias!
- [Traducción en español para “muscle cars”](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/19566)
  (walen) La pregunta en la que "conocí" al tal Carlos Alejo, un tío que hablaba de manera amable y respetuosa, que razonaba sus comentarios, que sin decirlo me hacía respaldar los míos con fuentes, y que no tenía problema en "liberar" sus respuestas haciéndolas CW si creía que con eso la respuesta sería mejor (y de paso aprendí lo que era una respuesta CW).
- [¿Existen palabras esdrújulas o llanas que acaben en “on”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/18855/existen-palabras-esdr%C3%BAjulas-o-llanas-que-acaben-en-on)
  (blonfu) Creo que ya me había cruzado con Charlie en el sitio en alguna pregunta o comentario pero esta fue mi primera pregunta y me descubrió dos cosas interesantes: Una que el DLE tenía un desplegable en su buscador para filtrar según ciertos criterios, un desplegable, por cierto, muy poco evidente, no lo había visto nunca antes y hacía mucho que usaba el DLE. La otra fue una palabra bastante rara: *Bustrofedon*, su sonoridad y su significado son curiosos pero es que además tiene todas las variantes de acentuación, puede ser aguda, llana o esdrújula.
  Siempre se aprende algo con sus respuestas y muchas veces también con sus preguntas, es un *crack*.
- [Etimología de “papis”](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/28592/5481)
  (Diego) Recuerdo haber visto esta pregunta y pensar "Ahí está el tío, a punto de ser padre por tercera vez y no deja de participar en el *stack* :-D" Bromas aparte, sirva esta pregunta para destacar la gran cantidad de tiempo y esfuerzo (y cariño) que Charlie ha dedicado a este *Stack*.
- [Plurales-volados](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/21524/fueron-comunes-en-alg%C3%BAn-momento-los-s%C3%ADmbolos-como-km-con-plurales-volados)
  (mdewey) Otro ejemplo de Charlie pensando en nosotros y en el sitio cuando está en la carretera.
- [¿Es la etimología de “salario” realmente relativa a la sal con que se pagaba a los soldados romanos?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/27335/1674)
  (fedorqui) Ejemplo paradigmático de Charlie arremangándose y tirando de todo el arsenal que ha ido construyendo con el tiempo: pregunta en otros sitios de la red Stack Exchange, consulta diccionarios de otros idiomas, razona sobre posibles hipótesis... uno se imagina a Charlie salivando mientras va abriendo pestañas del navegador con posibles ideas y creo que es una imagen muy bonita : )

Comment: Pasados ya unos días desde que se publicó esta respuesta, quería daros las gracias a todos los que habéis contribuido, y sobre todo por vuestras amables palabras. Como siempre, espero poder continuar sorprendiendo a propios y extraños con más y más preguntas y respuestas, ¡y poder sorprenderme con vuestras preguntas y respuestas, por supuesto! ¡Quedan muchas cosas por descubrir!