# Charlie renuncia a su puesto de moderador

Tags: discusión, moderadores

Muchos os habréis preguntado por qué se ha organizado una [elección](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/election) con un solo puesto. La razón es que [Charlie](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/12637/charlie) ha decidido renunciar a su puesto de moderador. El nuevo moderador que salga elegido cubrirá la plaza de Charlie, mientras que Glorfindel y yo nos mantendremos en el puesto. La decisión de hacerlo así se ha basado en los resultados del [interest check](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4447/24236), que indican que una elección competitiva con tres puestos es improbable.

Los que lleváis algo más de tiempo en el sitio sabéis que hay mucho que agradecer a Charlie. Es el [usuario con más reputación](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all), gracias entre otras cosas a su [insaciable interés](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:12637%20%5Betimolog%C3%ADa%5D) por la etimología y a sus [más de 1000 respuestas](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/12637/charlie?tab=answers&sort=votes). Fue moderador del sitio en solitario durante casi un año. La comunidad le mostró su aprecio con un [regalo](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3096/24236), y hay una lista de sus "[Greatest Hits](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3098/24236)". Si hay alguien que ha marcado la diferencia en la evolución de este sitio, ese es Charlie.

Charlie me ha pedido que anuncie yo su renuncia, que se debe a la existencia de otras prioridades. Aunque lo invito a escribir él una comunicación (que sería muy apreciada), respeto su decisión y le agradezco todas sus contribuciones al sitio.

Comment: Gracias por tus palabras, wimi. La vida, eso es lo que me ha pasado. Mi tiempo libre se ha reducido significativamente, entre el trabajo y la familia os podéis imaginar. Al final uno tiene que priorizar. He acabado siguiendo la senda que otros han recorrido antes que yo. En todo caso, espero no llegar a desvincularme completamente del sitio, y seguir aportando cuando sea posible.

Answer (score 8):

Gracias por tanto, Charlie.

- Gracias por enseñarnos que una pregunta puede ser la mejor excusa para hacer volar la imaginación, investigar y descubrir cosas sorprendentes.
- Gracias por enseñarnos que responder una pregunta de lengua se puede hacer incluyendo muchas vertientes del conocimiento.
- Gracias por recordarnos que tras cualquier usuario hay una persona; y que esa persona merece respeto y cariño. Siempre eres constructivo y pones a las personas por encima de las reglas (como [otro gran compañero, Diego](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/users/5481/diego))

Como moderador, apenas coincidí unos meses contigo. Después, tu labor de moderador me ha pasado muy desapercibida y creo que eso es un gran mérito: si no se ha notado, es que ha sido útil. Tuviste que lidiar solo con todo el peso de la moderación durante un tiempo largo y seguramente fue eso lo que salvó al sitio.

Recuerdo que hace unos años un futbolista batió un récord de velocidad y [dijo](https://cronometroderecords.blogspot.com/2009/03/joseba-llorente-de-ignorado-goleador-en.html): *... cuando alguien supere el registro dentro de diez o quince años volverán a acordarse de nosotros, que estaremos en casa tomando una cerveza y diremos: joder, cómo corría*. Espero que de aquí unos años te pase lo mismo: cerveza (o lo que sea) en mano, que mires atrás, pienses en lo que has hecho en Spanish Stack Exchange y te digas *joder, cómo respondía*. Yo creo que será así.

Lo dicho: gracias por tanto, Charlie. Un abrazo.

Comment: Eso ya me lleva pasando un tiempo, fedorqui. Es imposible que me acuerde de todo lo que he escrito, pero a veces me veo volviendo a alguna pregunta o respuesta y vuelvo a aprender gracias a lo que en su día aporté. Gracias a todos vosotros por acogerme en su día, y por supuesto por vuestras palabras y gestos de reconocimiento. Confío en no abandonar el sitio del todo, y en seguir aportando conforme vaya pudiendo.

Answer (score 6):

Personalmente creo que el post que mejor resume a Charlie es [Etimología de "papis"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/28592/5481). A punto de ser padre por tercera vez, y ahí estaba el tío, en plan de "esta es una pregunta interesante para el stack...".

La pasión y entrega al stack se traduce no solo en cuantiosas contribuciones, sino en posts de gran calidad que han contribuido a ayudar a múltiples usuarios, e inspirado a muchos otros a participar mejorando la calidad de sus propias contribuciones. En este stack, el usuario Charlie [*es leyenda*](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3096/5481).

No es extraño entonces que miembros de la comunidad [considerasen a Charlie candidato claro e idóneo para moderar el stack](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3102/5481).

Gracias Carlos no solo por el tiempo y esfuerzo invertido a moderar el stack, sino también en general por todas las contribuciones, desde los post concienzudamente documentados hasta los comentarios amables que han ayudado a solucionar disputas.

Ójala reines por mucho tiempo en [las ligas de reputación](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/353/alltime/spanish/2011-11-15/12637#12637).

Comment: No te pases, Diego, no soy legendario, solo [épico](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/badges/42/epic). :-) Bromas aparte, gracias por tus palabras. Me sigue pasando lo de pensar en alguna pregunta para el stack en los momentos más insospechados, solo que con menos frecuencia y pocas veces encuentro el momento para plantearla. La pregunta de [por qué se dice "miércoles" en Encanto](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/40332/12637) tenía que haberla planteado mucho antes, pero bueno, más vale tarde que nunca.